# colocar dados do MYSQL no combobox do meu form usando classe e php

Tags: php, combobox

Quero carregar no COMBOBOX do formulário de manutenção de cadastro de usuários os dados do NOME dos usuários vindo do MYSQL. Tenho um método abaixo que faz a consulta no banco de dados mysql e retorna um array

```
public function LerDadosUsu(){
    try{
        $lerusu = "SELECT * FROM usuario ";
        $listusu = $this->con->Connect()->prepare($lerusu);
        $listusu->execute();
        $retDados = $listusu->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $retDados;
        }
     catch(PDOException $erro_2){
     echo 'erro'.$erro_2->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Tenho o formulário abaixo que quero mostrar essa informação, mas onde esta o option value do combobox não traz a informação que ja existe no mysql

```
      <form method="post" name="frm_usuario">

                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <?php    

                                         echo '<label for="filter">Filtrar Usuário</label>

                                         <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span><select class="form-control">
                                         /*crio o objeto para buscar valor*/
                                         $objeto = new Usuario();
                                         $usuario = $objeto->LerDadosUsu();

                                         /*crio um foreach para retornar o campo*/   
                                         foreach($usuario as $usuario):

<option value="<?$usuario['.nom_usuario.'];?>"selected>Escolha o usuario</option>
                                         endforeach;
                                         </select>
                                        ?>

                       </div>
                       </div>
```

O erro que aparece no meu formulário quando estou executando é esse abaixo

ERRO: Use of undefined constant nom_usuario - assumed 'nom_usuario' in C:..\usuario.php on line 327

Comment: Sempre adicione a tag da linguagem na pergunta, isso é fundamental para indexar a pergunta e para facilitar para os respondedores da tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa arrumar o código. neste trecho `foreach($usuario as $usuario):
<option value="<?$usuario['.nom_usuario.'];?>"selected>Escolha o usuario</option>`você está misturando `PHP` e `HTML`.

```
<form method="post" name="frm_usuario">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="filter">Filtrar Usuário</label>
        <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            <select class="form-control">
            <?php
            /*crio o objeto para buscar valor*/
            $objeto = new Usuario();
            $usuario = $objeto->LerDadosUsu();
            /*crio um foreach para retornar o campo*/   
            foreach($usuario as $usuario):
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $usuario['.nom_usuario.'];?>"selected>Escolha o usuario</option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
            ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```